# How not to re-render a component when its output does not changes, but it's prop changes?

Tags: reactjs

Counter component is getting re-render on change of counter value in parent component, but output of component does not get changed from counter value 0 to 5. I tried to use memo but seems it does not work. Can anybody please help me to solve this problem.

````
import React, {memo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Counter = memo(({ counter }) => {
  alert("counter++++");
  const func = (counter) => {
    // alert(counter);
    if (counter >= 0 && counter <= 5) return "Red";
    else if (counter > 5 && counter <= 10) return "Green";
    return "Blue";
  };
  return <h2>{func(counter)}</h2>;
});
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>value of Counter {counter}</h1>
      <Counter counter={counter} />
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Increment by 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>Decrement by 1</button>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Are you by chance using `<StrictMode>`? If so, it's working as intended. In dev builds, strict mode deliberately double-renders components to help catch bugs. https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development

Comment: I think StrictMode is for different usages -

Comment: Does that mean "no, i'm not using strict mode"?

Comment: yes, its rendering one time only after commenting <strictMode>, read about this now. Thanks @NicholasTower and Benjamin to clarifying query.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that the Counter component renders twice every time the counter prop changes, specifically when React.StrictMode is enabled in development mode. This behavior might seem concerning at first, but it's actually an intentional feature of React.

During development, React intentionally renders components twice when React.StrictMode is enabled. This double invocation mechanism helps detect potential issues like impure render methods or side effects. However, it's important to note that this behavior is exclusive to development mode; in production mode, where React.StrictMode is disabled, the double rendering does not occur. React's optimizations ensure that rendering is efficient and streamlined in production.

For reference- https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#my-calculation-runs-twice-on-every-re-render

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `useMemo` ?
I don't really see a use-case for React.memo here.
Count changes on every interaction, right?
As others have already mentioned, rendering twice is intended in dev when using React.StrictMode around your App.
Usually, it is best not to reduce the amount of renders, but to reduce the amount of calculations that happen within a render first.

```js
import React, {useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const counterColor = (count) => {
   alert("color change");
   if (counter >= 0 && counter <= 5) return "Red";
   else if (counter > 5 && counter <= 10) return "Green";
   return "Blue";
};

const Counter = ({ count }) => {
  const color = useMemo(() => counterColor(count), [count]);
  
  return <h2>{color}</h2>;
};
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>value of Counter {counter}</h1>
      <Counter count={counter} />
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Increment by 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>Decrement by 1</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this scenario using `useMemo` is very debatable because `counterColor` is not heavy in calculation. Using counterColor directly is probably more efficient than wrapping it inside `useMemo`.